# Format a mathematical expression from user input to python

Tags: python, parsing, expression, mathematical-expressions

I want to be able convert the input of a mathematical expression from a user to the python format for math expressions. For example if the user input is:

> 3x^2+5

I want to be able to convert that into

> 3*x**2+5

so that I can user this expression in other functions. Is there any existing library that can accomplish this in Python?

Comment: [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html) maybe?

Comment: Why do you need a library? How many things do you need to translate? There aren't any real "non-standard" arithmetic symbols except for your example here, right?

Comment: I just want to be able to translate any mathematical expression from the user input, and that its parenthesis and symbols are correctly assigned.

Comment: I faced something similar... I just taught everyone who used the system to enter equations in valid Python.

Comment: There are some libraries that parse certain specific syntaxes. No idea which one you want to use though, your single example hardly scratches the surface of expression parsing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple string formatting to accomplish this.

```
import re

expression = "3x^2+5"

expression = expression.replace("^", "**")
expression = re.sub(r"(\d+)([a-z])", r"\1*\2", expression)
```

For more advanced parsing and symbolic mathematics in general, check out [SymPy](http://sympy.org)'s [`parse_expr`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html).